# Split a String after every n characters ignoring whitespaces in java store it in arraylist

Tags: java

I have a string which I want to split after every n characters and store the same in an array of strings, but this should ignore all the whitespaces.

For example I have a string as follows,

String str = "This is a String which needs to be splitted after every 10 characters";

The output should be,

["This is a Str", "ing which nee", "ds to be split", "ted after ev", "ery 10 chara", "cters"]

(Edit) --> I am using the function below. How can I store this in an array of Strings.

As seen in the output it ignores indexes of all the whitespaces. Is there any way to do it in java.

```
public static String test(int cnt, String string) {
        AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger(cnt);
        return string
                .chars()
                .boxed()
                .peek(value -> {
                    if (!Character.isWhitespace(value)) {
                        n.decrementAndGet();
                    }
                })
                .takeWhile(value -> n.get() >= 0)
                .map(Character::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a standard approach with looping through the string and counting chars:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String str = "This is a String which needs to be splitted after every 10 characters";
    System.out.println(split(str, 10));
}

public static List<String> split(String string, int splitAfter) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    int startIndex = 0;
    int charCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        if (charCount == splitAfter) {
            result.add(string.substring(startIndex, i));
            startIndex = i;
            charCount = 0;
        }
        // only count non-whitespace characters
        if (string.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            charCount++;
        }
    }
    // check if startIndex is less than string length -> if yes, then last element wont be 10 characters long
    if (startIndex < string.length()) {
        result.add(string.substring(startIndex));
    }
    return result;
}
```

And the result differs slightly from what you posted, but looking at your expected result, it doesn't quite match the description anyways:

```
[This is a Str, ing which ne, eds to be spl, itted after,  every 10 cha, racters]
```

Comment: This one works! Thank you so much!